# I would like to control Form1 from Form2 (textbox,picturebox)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, picturebox

I want to resize my picturebox in Form1 (picturebox1) using textbox1,textbox2 and button in Form2.

First I made this in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
 public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picturebox1;
```

After this in Form2.cs (submit button):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

        int height = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
        frm1.picturebox1.Height = height;
        int width = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);
        frm1.picturebox1.Width = width; 
}
```

But this not change the size of the picturebox1...

Comment: The "picture" and the "picturebox" are two separate concepts.  Which one do you want to modify?

Comment: is form 2 called from form 1?

Comment: `Form1 frm1 = new Form1()` creates a new instance of Form1. You want to change the already visible Form1. You can do so by passing a reference (see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273862/c-sharp-how-to-make-two-forms-reference-each-other)), but frankly, you don't want to do that, as now both forms are tightly coupled to each other. Use events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

You're creating a *new* instance of `Form1`.  So you're successfully modifying the values on that new instance, but doing nothing to the instance you already have.

`Form2` needs a reference to the *existing* instance, not create a new one.  You can supply that instance to `Form2` on its constructor for example.  Something like this:

```
private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }

public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    this.Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Then when you create an instance of `Form2` from `Form1`, you'd supply it the reference it needs:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

Then any code in `Form2` can act upon that instance of `Form1`.  Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int height = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    this.Form1Instance.picturebox1.Height = height;
    int width = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);
    this.Form1Instance.picturebox1.Width = width; 
}
```

Comment: David, you are making a huge assumption that the button click is *not supposed* to create a new Form1 instance.  The OP's description and code don't make an assumption like that warranted.

Comment: @Dan-o: I think it's a pretty small assumption.  In general when there's a `Form1` and a `Form2` (not better named) then I'd argue that in the vast majority of cases the control flow moves from the former to the latter.  And the fact that `.Show()` is never called on the new instance also supports this assumption.  As does the fact that the newly created `Form1` instance falls out of scope at the end of that click handler.  If the desired behavior is as you describe, every click would create and orphan a new `Form1`.  Doesn't seem like a plausible UX to me.