# Load data to a datagrid using another form

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I have two forms.
1st one is frmStudentDetails. It has a datagrid
2nd one is frmStudentRegistration. It has some text boxes and Add button

When user enter some information and press "Add" button, I want to add those to the datagrid one by one

For accomplish that 1st I created following method in frmStudentDetails

```
    public void AddRecord(string StID, string Name)
    {
       DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvStDetails.Rows[0].Clone();
       row.Cells[0].Value = StID;
       row.Cells[1].Value = Name;

       dgvStDetails.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

I called it on frmStudentRegistration form's add button -->

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       frmStudentDetailsForm frm = new frmStudentDetailsForm();
       frm.AddRecord(txtStudentID.Text, txtStName.Text);
       frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Then the problem is, itz generating new forms to show every new record.
But i want to add all records in one form.

please somebody help me for that

Comment: thats because you are in fact creating a new form with "new frmStudentDetailsForm()". You need to pass the reference of frmStudentDetails to frmStudentRegistration when you call it. This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273862/c-sharp-how-to-make-two-forms-reference-each-other

Comment: Declare frm as a variable of class initialized as null. in btnAdd_Click, create frm only if null.

Comment: I tried. but still i have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

1. In your "frmStudentRegistration" Class, add a "public frmStudentDetailsForm StudentDetailsForm { get; set; };" Property Declaration at the Class level.
2. Set it equal to the Instance of your "frmStudentDetailsForm" Class. There are several ways you can do so (i.e. in "frmStudentRegistration" Class's custom Constructor or its "Load" Event Handler), but for a novice, I would recommend just setting it after you Instantiate your "frmStudentRegistration" Class and before you call that Instance Variable's "Show" Method.  NOTE: If you call "frmStudentRegistration"'s "ShowDialog" Method, any updates to other Forms (i.e. "frmStudentDetailsForm") won't show on screen until you exit "ShowDialog" or you explicity call the other Form's "Show" or "ShowDialog" Methods.

On a side note, I'm curious as to why you're calling "frmStudentDetailsForm"'s "ShowDialog" Method from "frmStudentRegistration".  In my experience, either: a) the grid's Form would call "ShowDialog" on the add-item's Form with the "Add" option (i.e. via Button, Context Menu item, Insert Key and/or Enter Key (after filling in a new template Row)) being on the grid's Form or b) both Forms would remain open at the same time (via Modeless "Show" Method Calls) with the "Add" option on the add-item's form.  Btw, in my experience your "frmStudentRegistration" Form would be called the "frmStudentDetailsForm" and your "frmStudentDetailsForm" would be called something like "frmStudentsForm", "frmStudentsListForm" or "frmStudentSummariesForm", etc.  Also, btw, the .NET naming convention would be "var studentDetailsForm = new StudentDetailsForm()" (i.e. suffix vs. prefix/both and no abbrev.).  Actually, if were up to me, it would be "var StudentDetailsFrmObj = new StudentDetailsFrmCls()". ;)

Ex.

```
In "frmStudentRegistration":

public frmStudentDetailsForm StudentDetailsForm { get; set; }

public void main ()
{
    var studentRegistration = new frmStudentRegistration();
    var studentDetailsForm = new frmStudentDetailsForm();
    studentRegistration.StudentDetailsForm = studentDetailsForm;
    studentRegistration.Show();
}

In "frmStudentRegistration":

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StudentDetailsForm.AddRecord(txtStudentID.Text, txtStName.Text);
   StudentDetailsForm.ShowDialog();
}
```