# How to take value from form1 to form2 AND back?

Tags: c#, forms, reference, parent

Ok so here is the Situation:
I want to take a value of a string in form1 to a textbox in form2, edit it and send it back and save it as the string in form1 again. Its that easy but Im too stupid to succed. Yes I googled and tried very long but I just dont seem to find the right tags.
I tried it with the following Method:

```
public partial class form1: Form
{
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Project.form2 newform2 = new Project.form2();
    string oldtext = "Text here";

    void somefunction()
    {
        oldtext = newform2.getUpdateTxt();
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class form2: Form
{

    Project.form1 newform1 = new Project.form1();
    string UpdateTxt = "";
    public form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTxt = textBox1.Text;
        this.Hide();
    }

    public string getUpdateTxt()
    {
        return UpdateTxt;
    }

    private void form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         textbox1.Text = newform1.oldtext.Text;
    }
}
```

obviously not working. Because it creates an infinityloop. I also tried it by putting the

```
Project.form newform = new Project.form();
```

In an own function. Solves the loop but now it resets the values while initializing. Also tried to parent the forms somehow like described here but its not helping.
[C# - How to make two forms reference each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273862/c-sharp-how-to-make-two-forms-reference-each-other?rq=1)

Comment: `#inifinityloop #resetsvalues` whatever that means, dont do it.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]  #ThisIsntSocialMediaSite

Comment: Why not just make these strings public properties of the class?

Comment: @RufusL that isnt my problem. Its about the interaction between the two forms without causing loops or reseting values because of new initialization.

Comment: Can you please describe an actual example of what you're talking about? Your example where each form creates it's own private instance of the other form's class doesn't make sense to me. Wouldn't you want each form to interact with the *existing instance* of the form?

Comment: @RufusL My Situation is i have a List that gets displayed in a Listbox and when I double click on selected Item in Listbox a new Form opens to edit the Value and by clicking done its saving the new value to the list. And now i want to show the old value in the Form

Comment: You want to show the "old" value? What do you want to do with the "new" value (the one they edited on the second form)? You can create a public property of Form2 that contains the new value, and then after they close that form you can access `form2.NewValue`. I'll post a sample later today if you want, but won't have time for a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of for this is to put the value you want to share across forms in a static property of a static class:

```
public static class SharedVariables
{
    public static string OldText { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can set a `TextBox.Text` to the value of the property with:

```
textBox1.Text = SharedVariables.OldText;
```

And you can assign a new value entered in another `TextBox.Text` with:

```
SharedVariables.OldText = textBox2.Text;
```

That being said, depending on what the purpose of the forms are, this may not be the *best* solution.