# How to get a textboxt text as a string from other class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a form, called Form1 and a class, called Class1. On the form i have a textbox (textBox1) and a button (button1).

I want nothing else, just to set textBox1.Text as a string in Class1. I made a property in Form1.cs called TextValue but if i want to use it in Class1 as "string tv=Form1.TextValue;" an error occurs, that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.TextValue'". I think everything has set as non-static, but i am confused now.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string TextValue
        {
             get
            {
                return textBox1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox1.Text = value;
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        string tv=Form1.TextValue;
    }
}
```

Can you kindly help me how i should modify my code to be able to get the string "tv" with the textBox1.Text?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273862/c-sharp-how-to-make-two-forms-reference-each-other

Comment: In your `Class1` you would have to first instantiate a new instance of `Form1` (or have an instance passed into the constructor, or some other means of getting an instance) in order to access an instance property like `TextValue`. Currently the relationship between these two classes is not clear (which one would instantiate the other).

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, `TextValue` is not a static, true. In `Class1` you are attempting to declare a non-static member called `tv`. The problem is, you are initializing `tv` with the expression `Form1.TextValue`. In the context of that expression, the use of `Form1` is a type reference, so the compiler is "thinking" `TextValue` is static, which it is not.

Instead, you will need to instantiate `Class1` somewhere and, perhaps, pass in the textbox's value.

Something like this

```
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = new Class1(textbox1.Text);
}

...
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(string textboxText) => tv = textboxText;

    string tv;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i don't get any error but it seems it's still not working. I mean if i write a text to the textBox1, the variable "tv" in Class1 doesn't get the text as it's value.